Probability of largest selected number with and without replacement

There are $n$ balls numbered $1, 2, \dots, n$. Now, $r$ balls are selected at random (a) with replacement, and (b) without replacement. What is the probability that the largest selected number is $m$?

My approach:
(a) With replacement:
Let $E_i$ denote the event that all $r$ balls chosen are less than $i$. Then,
\begin{align}
P(\text{largest selected number} = m) 
&= P(E_{m+1}) - P(E_m) \\
&= \biggl(\frac{m}{n}\biggr)^r - \biggl(\frac{m-1}{n}\biggr)^r.
\end{align}
(b) Without replacement:
In this case,
$$
P(\text{largest selected number} = m) 
= \binom{r}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\binom{m-1}{r-1}}{\binom{n-1}{r-1}}.
$$
Am I correct?

If $m<r$ the "without replacement " expression term is singular. Presumably you meant to set it to $0$ in that case.

yes, for m<r, P(largest selected number=m) =0. However, is the expression correct for m>=r  ("without replacement") ?

With that restriction, yes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You could also write (b) as $\frac{{m \choose r}-{m-1 \choose r}}{n \choose r}$
